# PHP form submit and redirect

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

So I have a modal form where I want to get the inputted fields and send it to my desired email address and then redirect it to a certain webpage/download page
I have managed to do it with PHP however I want to redirect it using client side and just use PHP mail for the field parsing to get the email and I have to create tons of PHP forms just to do so because the redirect url is different on many cases.

Here is the PHP

```
$to = "some@email.com";
$subject = "Contact Page";
$headers = "From: Contact Page";
$forward = 1;
$location = "somelocation";
$date = date ("l, F jS, Y");
$time = date ("h:i A");

$msg = "Below is the result of your feedback form. It was submitted on $date at $time.\n\n";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                $msg .= ucfirst ($key) ." : ". $value . "\n";
        }
}
else {
        foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
                $msg .= ucfirst ($key) ." : ". $value . "\n";
        }
}
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
if ($forward == 1) {
    print("You will be redirected to your download link shortly";) 
    header ("Location:$location");
}
else {
    include("index.html");
}
```

now the html

```
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">x</span>
    <form method="POST" onsubmit="myFunction()" action="form2.php"> 

<label for='name'>Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="name" >
<label for='email'>Email: </label>
<input type="text" name="email" >
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
<script>
function myFunction() { 
alert("form Submitted Successfully you will be redirected shortly");
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to redirect the page using Javascript? Also, you should write your question using better punctuation. It is easier to read that way.

Comment: Where is the closing </form> tag? You have the JavaScript code within the form as of right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's window.location.assign() function to redirect to another page. Try the following.

```
<script>
   function myFunction() { 
     alert("form Submitted Successfully you will be redirected shortly");
     window.location.assign("http://urlOfThePageYouWantToRedirectTo");
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place this piece of code in your **form2.php** file.

Keep in mind that you need HTML code inside your **form2.php** file for this to work.
 Make sure you place it under head tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://YourRedirectLink.com/" />
```

Change the **value** of **content** attribute if you want to delay the redirect (in seconds).

Comment: iam able to redirect on php using header ("Location:$location"); but i want to redirect it from client side as i have to create seperate php forms for each modal forms

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you submit your form via ajax and redirect it on successful response.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
//ajax code
//on success 

   alert("form Submitted Successfully you will be redirected shortly");
   //Redirect on url you want
   window.location.href= "write_your_url_here";

}
</script>
```

Comment: dont know ajax can u guide me here

Comment: SO is not a "learn to code" site - there are a zillion tuturials on doing ajax with PHP, just search for it.